# Filling out the chrome Extension Icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, chrome-web-store

Why are some extensions like [TeamVViewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/teamviewer/oooiobdokpcfdlahlmcddobejikcmkfo) filled out. But then there are others that are super small inside a jigsaw piece like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-hover-text/phhpajlkjeoakfmckfnogpnfeidgbhil)?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that TeamViewer is a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), not an extension.

All extensions' icons in CWS are rendered inside the jigsaw pieces.

It only affects the Store listing, your icon inside Chrome will be normal.